# If $a, b\in\mathbb{R}, a^2 + \left(\frac{b}{a}\right) ^2=0$ what can we conclude from "$a$" and "$b$"?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> $a, b\in\mathbb{R}, a^2 + \left(\dfrac{b}{a}\right) ^2=0$, what can we conclude from "$a$" and "$b$"?

I don't know if I'm right, but according to my logic, it's impossible to find an "$a$" and "$b$" to solve this problem.

Comment: What exactly is your logic?

Comment: Please explain why it is impossible to find $a, b$ satisfying the equation.  You're right, or rather we can say $b$ must necessarily be $0$, but there is no $a$ that will satisfy the equation.  Why not?  Why *you* think it's impossible to find such an $a\in \mathbb R$?

Comment: Since que equation is the sum of two squares such is ZERO, each number should be zero, thus, $a=0$, but $a$ can'y be zero by the second term of the sum.

Comment: Exactly, and we know $a$ can't be $0$ in the second term of the sum, whatever number $b$ is, $\frac b0$ is undefined, right?  Why don't you write up an answer to your question, with your explanation, etc., and post it below as an answer?

Comment: "ince que equation is the sum of two squares such is ZERO, each number should be zero"  What if one was positive and the other negative?  Would that be possible?  Why or why not?

Answer (score -1):

Squaring a number makes it non negative. Now you have on the left hand side two squares (two non negative numbers) added up, what would happen if one of them will be positive?